# Function in VBA for multiple filter

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Can someone help me write VBA function to get data from another worksheet using multiple filter?
Data looks something like this.

[image]

I want to write a function that extract the A1 or A2 or A3 value based on the dropdown I select. If I select A3 it should pick data from A3 column. My Filter criteria on other columns are Item, id and location. Column for Item, id and location are static. While column for A1, A2, A3 are dynamic. I want to put criteria on Ite, id and location. These are the three criteria and result should be from the fourth column. i.e. either A1 or A2 or A3 based on what I select.

I tried but couldn't figure out. Can someone help me on this, please?

Comment: Another worksheet in the same workbook?  Can you edit with what you've tried?

Comment: Do you insist on a VBA function?

Comment: Yes, Data is on another worksheet.

Comment: @PRAVEENKUMAR although the data is on another *Worksheet*, the key info we are missing is, is the *other worksheet* in the same **OR** a different *Workbook*? - Also, *"I tried but couldn't figure it out."* - what did you already try? Edit your question to include your code, even if it *'doesn't work'*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need VBA for this but you do need to make a few preparations. I will show here what I did. There are other ways and you can choose the way you prefer.

1. I created a table exactly as you posted. Instead of a table you can just create a named range or you can replace the names of either in the formulas with the range's coordinates. I didn't name the table but recommend that you do if you use a table. In my example the table's name is `Table1`.
2. Within the table I created a named range comprising the cells D1:F1. I called this range "Data" but any other name will do as well. You may also move the named range entirely elsewhere if you want different captions for the columns for one reason or another. As you will see, the names are insignificant they are used to create the numbers 1, 2 and 3 from the location where they are within the named range `Data`.
3. Now I created a validation drop-down referring to a *List* of `=Data`. The effect is that I have a drop-down with A1, A2 and A3 in it. I created this drop-down in A10 of a different sheet from the one on which I have *Table1*.

Now I used the following formulas to extract data from row 2 of the table.

```
=INDEX(Table1[Item],2)
=INDEX(Table1[Location],2) or =INDEX(Table1,2,3) and
=INDEX(Table1,2,3+MATCH(A10,Data,0))
```

Observe that every "2" in the above formulas refers to the 2nd row in the named range `Table1`. I didn't set up a range of that name but that is something Excel threw in when I created the table. However, you would like to pull data from other rows as well.

For that purpose you can use the ROW() function. This function returns the number of the row in which it resides. If it's in row 10 it will return 10, in row 11 it returns 11 etc. It's a counter. Therefore, if you entered my formulas in row 10 you can replace all the "2"s with `Row()-8` and as you copy up or down you will get data from different rows, same columns.

```
=INDEX(Table1[Item],Row()-8)
=INDEX(Table1[Location],Row()-8) or =INDEX(Table1,Row()-8,3) and
=INDEX(Table1,Row()-8,3+MATCH(A10,Data,0))
```

If your first formula isn't in row 10 you must adjust the number to be deducted according to where your formula was entered.